# Microcontroller freezing up when I connect a motor

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, motor

[image]

The out pin is a PWM feeding into the npn transistor to control the speed of the motor. The motor is a small dc motor I found from a toy, and the transistor is the 2n2222. The microcontroller I'm using is a Tiva C. 3.3V and 9V are seperate power sources.

There is an Arduino to the left not drawn that generates a digital signal from an IR LED using the NEC protocol. The IR reciever filters out the carrier and feeds the raw digital signal to the microcontroller. The micrcontroller is coded to recognize two patterns; one to increase duty cycle and one to decrease.

When the duty cycle goes above some value, typically in the ballpark of 30%, the microcontroller freezes up and is not responsive to inputs. I have an LED that always blinks at 1Hz, but that also freezes when the motor is connected. As soon as I disconnect the motor, the microcontroller works fine and the duty cycle can vary the entire range and the LED resumes blinking. If I replace the motor with a resistive load, everything works fine.

Comment: Is the 3.3V derived from the 9V? Is the motor pulling the 9V down? If the answer to those questions is 'no' then it would be good to provide a photo of your lash-up.

Comment: The 3.3V and the 9V are separate sources.

Comment: Please show your full schematic. Where is your decoupling?

Comment: I added the capacitors in the schematic. I tried 10n and 4.7u.

Comment: Try 100uF capacitors

Comment: @Shock-o-lot: Can you post the schematic inline so we all don't have to follow links and the question will still make sense if the link dies.

Comment: Yep, I'll do that.

Comment: Can you do a simple experiment. Exclude receiver from circuit and either hard-code low speed value as input to your PWM generation or connect a potentiometer to analog input and use that as speed value. And test again with resistor and motor.

Comment: You may have a 'ground loop' which is injecting noise into the Tiva's ground when the motor draws high current. Show us a photo of your setup (including all power supplies, wiring, motor etc.).